# FullCalendar undo event drag 'n drop with info.revert() throws error

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to display calendar events.  I let the admin user reschedule an event by dragging an event to a different calendar day.  If they try to reschedule an event to a day that cannot accept an event, the code uses info.revert() to "undo" the drag 'n drop.

All that works fine.  However, when I show 2 calendars side-by-side (useful if they want to reschedule an event to a different month), I try to run the same code, but info.revert() throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: info.revert is not a function
```

I see from the documentation here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive that info.revert() should work here.  Can anyone help me out?

FYI, here is my calendar defintion:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(cal, {
plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'dayGridPlugin', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
events: 'ajax/calendar.php?action=get_monthly_patrol_calendar',
showNonCurrentDates:false,
isRTL: KTUtil.isRTL(),
contentHeight: 'auto',
nowIndicator: show_now_indicator,
now: TODAY,
defaultDate: TODAY,
initialDate: TODAY,
defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
eventOrder: 'order_by',
navLinks: true,
eventLimit: false, // true to allow "more" link when too many events
eventResizableFromStart: false, //Whether the user can resize an event from its starting edge.
eventDurationEditable: false, //Allow events’ durations to be editable through resizing.
eventResourceEditable: true, //Determines whether the user can drag events between resources.
droppable:true, //Determines if external draggable elements or events from other calendars can be dropped onto the calendar.
eventStartEditable: true, //Allow events’ start times to be editable through dragging.
editable: true, //Determines whether the events on the calendar can be modified.
eventDrop: function(info) { //fires when drag to another date in the same calendar month
  if (info.event.extendedProps.has_events==true) {
    reschedule_event(info);
  }
  else {
    info.revert();      
  }
},
eventReceive: function(info) { //fires when drag to another date in the A DIFFERENT calendar month      
  if (info.event.extendedProps.has_events==true) {
    reschedule_event_to_new_month(info);
  }
  else {
    info.revert(); //////////////////////////this is the code that throws the error!!!!!! 
  }
},
eventClick: function(info) {
  do_event_click(info);
},
eventRender: function(info) {
    var element = $(info.el);
},
header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev,next today',//'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
}, 
}); 
calendar.render();
```

Comment: From some bits of the code (and judging by the error message) it looks to me like you're probably using version 4 of fullCalendar (but also getting confused and using occasional bits from version 5 because you're reading the wrong documentation). If you check the version 4 documentation for eventReceive you'll see that it doesn't contain the revert function: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventReceive. I suggest upgrading. The upgrade guide is here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4

Comment: I did not realize that I was mixing versions.  That is definitely the issue here.  I will look into upgrading.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention!